# Change array structure

Tags: javascript

I have a `categoriesWithSub` array that has a `category` object and `subCategory` objects array with the following structure:

```
[{
    category: {},
    subCategory: [] // The array of subCategories for this category.
}]
```

This is the code that set the `categoriesWithSub` array:

```
const categories = await getCategories();
const subCategories = await Promise.all(categories.map(category => getSubCategories(category.id)));
const categoriesWithSub = zipWith(categories, subCategories, (category, subCategory) => ({
  category,
  subCategory,
}));
```

How can I update the code to combine the categories and subcategories according to the following structure:

```
[{
    category: {
       id: '',
       catName: '',
       subCategories: []
    },
}]
```

Comment: Please click the `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve] of your efforts

Comment: Change the `zipWith` callback to create the structure that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could directly do that when mapping:

```
 const categories = await getCategories();

 const result = await Promise.all(categories.map(async category => {
  const subCategories = await getSubCategories(category.id);
  return { ...category, subCategories };
}));
```

Or to keep your `zipWith`:

```
 const result = zipWith(categories,  subCategories, (category, subCategories) => ({
   ...category,
   subCategories,
 }));
```